# How can I encrypt my "users" drive?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt

I am currently running Windows 7.  My User folder is mapped to a different drive then the drive that my OS in installed on.  I mapped the users folder to the other drive while installing windows.

I want to encrypt the whole drive with the "Users" folder.  Is there any way I can use TrueCrypt to encrypt the whole drive, but make it so Windows can still have access to it upon booting?

[image]

Comment: How is the Users folder linked? Is it a hard link or symlink? I believe you can use BitLocker to encrypt A: if you use a hard link it might ask for a password when you startup. Just a theory.

Comment: It is not linked.  Windows is actually looking at that location for the users folder.  I followed these instructions when installing http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/win7-how-do-i-move-user-folder-to-a-different/565f16a5-e5ed-43c9-8422-4f56aebb296e?page=2

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt a **whole** drive? Afterwards access times could be terrible, since you need to decrypt every time you need to access data, AFAIK.

Comment: The method in the article is making a "junction" which is essentially a hard link. Mounting a drive to an empty folder. I'm guessing you want to encrypt the partition not the entire drive. Should be possible using BitLocker.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Actually the drivers truecrypt uses for whole drive encryption are fairly fast, from what I have seen worst case 10% performance loss, but normally only 1 or 2%

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Since I have my system, user folder, and software spread across 3 different SSDs/HDD, I can encrypt my files on the HDD, and still have SSD performance for my apps on a different drive.

Comment: I would assume that using [boot time encryption](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-encryption) should work fine. Then you'll unlock the drive before Windows is even booted. I'm not sure if it *has* to be the system drive for that to work though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt a partition with [pre-boot authentication](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-encryption). Start with [this](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/tutorial) tutorial and use hidden TrueCrypt volume in step 4.

More information about encryption softwares can be found from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software) Wikipedia page along with a good comparison charts.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but it seems pre-boot authentication requires you to encrypt the system volume as well. Can it be done without it?